# Wowza adaptive streaming to jwplayer with secure token

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

I have a wowza (4.5) server with a smil file to generate adaptative streaming of videos and I want to play them in a website with jwplayer.

Currently it works fine in:

- safari in MacOS
- iPhones
- Android devices
- Microsoft Edge

But it doens't work with

- Chrome (Ios or Windows)
- Firefox
- Opera

I've added the Mpeg Dash, MS Smooth, and HDS urls to the jwplayer but all of them says "Error loading player: No playable resources found"

These are the urls generated:

**HDS**

[http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1935/vod/*definst*/test2/smil.smil/manifest.f4m?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf](http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1935/vod/_definst_/test2/smil.smil/manifest.f4m?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf)........

Using this url in the wowza test player (https://www.wowza.com/testplayers) it works fine, but no in jwplayer.

**HLS:**

[http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX1935/vod/*definst*/test2/smil.smil/playlist.m3u8?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf](http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX1935/vod/_definst_/test2/smil.smil/playlist.m3u8?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf)........

**Mpeg Dash:**

[http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1935/vod/*definst*/test2/smil.smil/manifest.mpd?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf](http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1935/vod/_definst_/test2/smil.smil/manifest.mpd?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf)........

Opening this url in bitmovin test player (http://bitmovin.com/hls-mpeg-dash-test-player/) works fine, but no in jwplayer.

**MS SMooth:**

[http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1935/vod/*definst*/test2/smil.smil/Manifest?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf](http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:1935/vod/_definst_/test2/smil.smil/Manifest?wowzatokencustomParam=customValue&wowzatokenstarttime=1475490378&wowzatokenendtime=1476354378&wowzatokenhash=UCxzWfNmhPyHgCG0uoQf)........

Opening this url in VLC player works fine, but no in jwplayer.

So, how can I make this work in jwplayer in chrome, firefox, etc?

This is my jwplayer code where $urls have an array of all smil urls files:

```
jwplayer('my_video').setup({
    sources: [
        <?php
        foreach($urls as $url) {
            echo '{file: "'.$url.'"},'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        ?>
        { file: '<?php echo $url ?>'}
    ],
    height: 360,
    width: 640,
    debug : true
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which version/edition of JW Player do you have? HLS and DASH require JW7+ with a Premium edition license key. You can test out your streams with JW Player before buying a Premium key using their stream tester: http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester

Comment: It works fine with the tester, so that is the problem I guess. Thank you!!